# Generate a dependency build number using a task

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am attempting to generate a build number for an artifact using a task and then plug that into my dependency.  My task looks something like this:

```
task getCurrentBuild() {
 doFirst{
    if(! file('/folder/dailyBuildNumber.txt').exists()) {
        assert false,'Cannot find latest runtime build at /folder/dailyBuildNumber.txt'
    }
    else {
        ext.set("myVersion", file('folder/dailyBuildNumber.txt').getText('UTF-8'))
    }
  }
}
```

while my dependencies look something like this:

```
 latestArtifactCompile "com.example.1.0-${project.ext.get("myVersion")}"
```

I am getting errors that it cannot find the extra or get the property myVersion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doFirst` closures are executed during *execution phase*, but the `dependencies` closure is executed before, during the *configuration phase*.

Why do you want to generate your dependency in a task? This seems to me like a regular and mandatory configuration required for each build, not depeding on the tasks you execute.

Comment: I am using it for build automation and we are testing against the latest version of an internal library.  This catches early regressions before they become a problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want to achieve, but I do not understand why you use a task. Gradle build scripts are Groovy scripts, you can apply your logic directly in the definition of the dependency instead of using a task.

Comment: That is what I wound up doing.